# Putting sequence number on the data points in a R Plot

Tags: r, plot, gps

I am plotting longitude and latitude values with different colors. Is there any way that i can put the sequence number (1,2,3 ... as shown in figure below) on the points that have been plotted. I want to see the transition of a person from one longitude and latitude pair to an other.

```
 require(ggplot2)
 df <- data.frame(x = rpois(10, 5), y = rpois(10, 5), group = 1:10)
 g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(group)))
 g <- g + geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA),
                      yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), tail(y, n = 1))),
                  arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
 g <- g + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + xlab("longitude") + 
 ylab("latitude") 
 g
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFhi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The key is the `label` aesthetic and `geom_text`. I also used the `jitter` function to avoid the overlap between the arrows and the text

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rpois(10, 5), y = rpois(10, 5), group = 1:10)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(group),label = group))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA),
                          yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), tail(y, n = 1))),
                      arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
g <- g + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + xlab("longitude") +
  ylab("latitude") + geom_text(aes(x = jitter(x), y = jitter(y)))
g
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :)